# Canvas .fillText not working after the first time

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html5-canvas

I'm using jCaptcha.js to generate captcha for my application. It works perfectly for the first time once I'm done with the signup & logout & try to signup new acc. the canvas doesn't print anything it shows blank & because of it, it goes in a loop cos I setup a check to see if it comes blank.

```
if ($('.jCaptchaText')[0].toDataURL() != $('#blankCaptcha')[0].toDataURL())
isCaptchaBlank = false;
```

jCaptcha.js

```
! function(t, a) {
    "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define([], function() {
        return t.jCaptcha = a()
    }) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = a() : t.jCaptcha = a()
}(this, function() {
    var t = function(t, a) {
            return "function" != typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach && (NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach), Object.keys(a).forEach(function(e) {
                t[e] = a[e]
            }), t
        },
        a = function() {
            n = Math.round(8 * Math.random()) + 1, c = Math.round(8 * Math.random()) + 1, i = n + c
        },
        e = function(t, a, e) {
            !e && t[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", '<canvas class="jCaptchaText"></canvas>'), this.$captchaText = this.$captchaText || document.getElementsByClassName("jCaptchaText"), this.$jCaptchaTextContext = this.$jCaptchaTextContext || this.$captchaText[0].getContext("2d"), this.$captchaText[0].width = a.canvasWidth, this.$captchaText[0].height = a.canvasHeight, this.$jCaptchaTextContext.textBaseline = "top", this.$jCaptchaTextContext.font = a.canvasFontSize + " " + a.canvasFontFamily, this.$jCaptchaTextContext.textAlign = "left", this.$jCaptchaTextContext.fillStyle = a.canvasFillStyle, this.$jCaptchaTextContext.fillText(n + " + " + c + " " + a.requiredValue, 0, 0)
        },
        i = void 0,
        n = void 0,
        c = void 0,
        o = function(a) {
            this.options = a ? t(this.options, a) : this.options, this.init()
        };
    return o.prototype = {
        options: {
            el: "jCaptcha",
            requiredValue: "=",// vinaya20180820 - made required value text as "=". it was * originally.
            resetOnError: !0,
            focusOnError: !0,
            clearOnSubmit: !0,
            canvasWidth: 50,
            canvasHeight: 15,
            canvasFontSize: "15px",
            canvasFontFamily: "Arial",
            canvasFillStyle: "#fff",
            callback: null
        },
        init: function() {
            this.$captchaInput = document.getElementsByClassName(this.options.el), a(), e(this.$captchaInput, this.options)
        },
        validate: function() {
            this.callbackReceived = this.callbackReceived || "function" == typeof this.options.callback, this.$captchaInput[0].value != i ? (this.callbackReceived && this.options.callback("error", this.$captchaInput), !0 === this.options.resetOnError && this.reset(), !0 === this.options.focusOnError && this.$captchaInput[0].focus(), !0 === this.options.clearOnSubmit && (this.$captchaInput[0].value = "")) : (this.callbackReceived && this.options.callback("success", this.$captchaInput), !0 === this.options.clearOnSubmit && (this.$captchaInput[0].value = ""))
        },
        reset: function() {
            a(), e(this.$captchaInput, this.options, !0)
        }
    }, o
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added a `location.reload(true)` when I redirect to login page again(where the captcha is initialized). This worked for me. Don't know if it has some cache issue or something with .filltext but reload seems to fix it. Please let me know if there is better solution.